# How to change Repeater DataSourceID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater and and and I set its `DataSourceID` .

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpProducts" runat="server" DataSourceID="ItemDataSource" >
    <HeaderTemplate>....</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       ....
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I some time I want to change the `DataSourceID` and load data and again set the `ItemDataSource`.

This is my code for change the rpProducts `DataSourceID` .

```
rpProducts.DataSourceID = null;
rpProducts.DataSource = goods;
rpProducts.DataBind();
```

So then again I want to set the `DataSourceID` to `ItemDataSource`.

How can I do it?

I try like this. but is not working

```
    rpProducts.DataSourceID = null;
    rpProducts.DataSourceID = ItemDataSource.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with: ItemDataSource.ID
Also, both datasource and datasourceid cannot be set at same time, so you will have to set the datasource to null.

```
rpProducts.DataSource = null;
rpProducts.DataSourceID = ItemDataSource.ID;
rpProducts.DataBind();
```