# Display column name and column value dynamically in desired style in Repeater ASP.NET control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

All i need is to display data in a repeater or any other control like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDT">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="NAME OF FIRST COLUMN" runat="server" ID="NameLabel" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label Text="VALUE OF FIRST COLUMN" runat="server" ID="ValueLabel" />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and then if i changed `DataSourceID` in code behind, repeater dynamically display new data in the same format.
**Why i need to do this?**
because there are many tables in my data base and i don't want to design a repeater for each table.

thank you very much.

Comment: Please have a look at that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181685/how-to-change-repeater-datasourceid)

Comment: can you show the code behind? are you rebinding it when changing the datasource?

Comment: consider i just change select command of datasource from "select * from mobile" to "select * from WashingMachine"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column name in the OnItemCreated event of the Repeater.

e.g.

```
DataRowView rowview = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
DataRow row = rowview.Row;
foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
   {
      nameOfColumn = col.ColumnName;
      // then add that to the relevant control in the row
   }
```

If the number of columns is variable depending on table - then you will need to look at using nested repeaters and some code behind to control those.

Comment: thank you. I need to the repeater generate an item template for each column. in your post it seems i have to design all the items and the give them the value and the name of the columns. or maybe i hav misundrestood

Comment: well i used this code :` nameOfColumn.Text += "<div class='col-md-12'>" + col.ColumnName + "</div>" ;`
now all columns are displaying. then i need to get value of every column. how can i achieve this? something like `col.ColumnValue`